# Incorrect docker compose on phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, docker, phpmyadmin, docker-compose, mariadb

According to the docker compose yaml,

```
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    image: mariadb:latest
    container_name: mariadb
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./mysql/initdb/:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
      - ./mysql/data/:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root-pwd
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=appdb
      - MYSQL_USER=appuser
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=user-pwd
  php:
    image: php:fpm-alpine
    container_name: php
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./www/:/var/www/html
    expose:
      - "9000"
  nginx:
    image: nginx:alpine
    container_name: nginx
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/conf/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf/nginx.conf:ro
      - ./nginx/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d:ro
      - ./www:/var/www/html
    ports:
      - "80:80"
  pma:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    container_name: phpmyadmin
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
```

it produces an error:

> #2002 - php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Try again — The server is not responding (or the local server's socket is not correctly configured).

when logging in to phpMyadmin (http://127.0.0.1:8080).

I have tried to fix this problem, but nothing works.
Could you please find a solution?
Any recommendations/comments are welcomed here.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem try this in the links directive - container-name:db as below

links:
   - mariadb:db

Answer (score 0):

you should `links` your phpmyadmin to database services in order to use the `db` service

```
pma:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    links:
      - db
    container_name: phpmyadmin
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    environment:
      - PMA_HOST: maria_db
```

here is more about docker compose  [services links](https://docs.docker.com/docker-cloud/apps/service-links/)

Comment: I have tried your suggestion, however, it still produces the same error.

Comment: seems like dns thing. . try pass mysql to pma host env variable
 `PMA_HOST: maria_db`

Answer (score 0):

If you set the following environment variable in docker compose:

```
pma:
  environment:
    - PMA_ARBITRARY=1
```

then you will be given the opportunity to enter the host server manually on the login screen. Enter the name of the database service there. In your case the name of the service is `db`